# Editing R studio theme in cache.css theme file (ACE editor?)

Tags: css, r, rstudio

In RStudio, I have found the cache.css files for the different themes in Rstudio. They are text files with code like this:

```html
.ace_editor { border: 2px solid rgb(159, 159, 159); } .ace_editor.ace_focus { border: 2px solid #327fbd; } .ace_gutter { background: #232323; color: #F8F8F8; } .ace_print_margin { width: 1px; background: #232323; } .ace_scroller { background-color: #141414;
} .ace_text-layer { color: #F8F8F8; } .ace_cursor { border-left: 2px solid #A7A7A7; } .ace_cursor.ace_overwrite { border-left: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid #A7A7A7; } .ace_marker-layer .ace_selection { background: rgba(221, 240, 255, 0.20); } .multiselect
.ace_selection.start { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #141414; border-radius: 2px; } .ace_marker-layer .ace_step { background: rgb(102, 82, 0); } .ace_marker-layer .ace_bracket { margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); } .ace_marker-layer
.ace_active_line { background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.031); } .ace_gutter_active_line { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.031); } .ace_marker-layer .ace_selected_word { border: 1px solid rgba(221, 240, 255, 0.20); } .ace_invisible { color: rgba(255,
255, 255, 0.25); } .ace_keyword, .ace_meta { color:#CDA869; } .ace_constant, .ace_constant.ace_other { color:#CF6A4C; } .ace_constant.ace_character, { color:#CF6A4C; } .ace_constant.ace_character.ace_escape, { color:#CF6A4C; } .ace_invalid.ace_illegal
{ color:#F8F8F8; background-color:rgba(86, 45, 86, 0.75); } .ace_invalid.ace_deprecated { text-decoration:underline; font-style:italic; color:#D2A8A1; } .ace_support { color:#9B859D; } .ace_support.ace_constant { color:#CF6A4C; } .ace_fold { background-color:
#AC885B; border-color: #F8F8F8; } .ace_support.ace_function { color:#DAD085; } .ace_storage { color:#F9EE98; } .ace_variable { color:#AC885B; } .ace_string { color:#8F9D6A; } .ace_string.ace_regexp { color:#E9C062; } .ace_comment { fontSize:4pt;font-style:italic;
color:#996633; } .ace_variable { color:#7587A6; } .ace_xml_pe { color:#494949; } .ace_meta.ace_tag { color:#AC885B; } .ace_entity.ace_name.ace_function { color:#AC885B; } .ace_markup.ace_underline { text-decoration:underline; } .ace_markup.ace_heading
{ color:#CF6A4C; } .ace_markup.ace_list { color:#F9EE98; } .ace_indent-guide { background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAACCAYAAACZgbYnAAAAEklEQVQImWMQERH5zzBz5sz/AA5EBAYqeZXWAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) right repeat-y; } .nocolor.ace_editor
.ace_line span {color:#CDA869 !important;} .ace_bracket {margin: 0 !important; border: 0 !important; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);} .ace_marker-layer .ace_foreign_line {position: absolute; z-index: -1; background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);}
.ace_marker-layer .ace_find_line {position: absolute; z-index: -1; background-color: rgb(134, 134, 134);} .ace_marker-layer .ace_active_debug_line {position: absolute; z-index: -1; background-color: rgb(137, 121, 38);} .ace_console_error { background-color:
rgb(65, 65, 65); }
```

I am trying to edit in these, and I could use some help. So far, I have only been able to change the colour of "comments" by finding and changing the colour indicated after the "ace.comment" command. But I would like to do something similar with things like the background colour, text colour, and colour of commands in R,  colour of curly brackets, etc, etc.

Is this possible? If so, what things do I need to edit in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is indeed possible. (Remember to restart Rstudio after each change)

I have no experience about ACE stuff, but it's not so hard to get the meaning of the different variables.. e.g

```
.ace_constant.ace_numeric {
  color: #4ef971;
}  
...

.ace_string {
  color: #6A8F9D;
 }
...
.ace_keyword {
 color: #85cfda;
 }
```

are, respectively, colors of numeric objects, strings and keywords (built in-functions and console)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the default web inspector with RStudio made it difficult to make edits. I have been trying for days to get folded comments to have different font attributes based on sections.

I found it was much easier using ATOM (see screenshot below). Once I found out what each variable changed I created comments in the `css` file to make it easier for me next time I edit. You can see in ATOM the color is shown, making it easier to identify what the variable is defining.

I am not sure if this is optimal but it is as far as I have got. I don't know why people don't comment on variable definitions, especially since some of them are not intuitive.

[image: CSS Editing in RStudio]